Straight skeleton bisectors are wrong when edges are collinear
When I try to use scikit-geometry to generate the straight skeleton of a polygon where two subsequent edges are collinear (i.e., the angle between them is pi), the bisector of the corner between those edges is wrong: it is not perpendicular to the edges.
In the example below, this happens for the bisectors originating from the points 7 and 3, probably because the edges (6,7) and (7,0) are collinear, as well as the edges (2,3) and (3,4).

import skgeom as sg
from skgeom.draw import draw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = [[0.304267912, -0.305884719],
 [0.5, -1.0],
 [0.695732088, -0.305884719],
 [0.75, -5.55111512e-17],
 [0.804267912, 0.305884719],
 [0.5, 0.0],
 [0.195732088, 0.305884719],
 [0.25, 0.0]]

def draw_skeleton(polygon, skeleton, show_time=False):
    draw(polygon)

    for h in skeleton.halfedges:
        if h.is_bisector:
            p1 = h.vertex.point
            p2 = h.opposite.vertex.point
            plt.plot([p1.x(), p2.x()], [p1.y(), p2.y()], 'r-', lw=2)

    if show_time:
        for v in skeleton.vertices:
            plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(plt.Circle(
                (v.point.x(), v.point.y()),
                v.time, color='blue', fill=False))

poly = sg.Polygon([sg.Point2(p[0], p[1]) for p in points])
draw(poly)

plt.scatter([p[0] for p in points], [p[1] for p in points], c='black', s=100, zorder=10)

skel = sg.skeleton.create_interior_straight_skeleton(poly)
draw_skeleton(poly, skel)

I understand that maybe technically the 'shrinking' process that defines the straight skeleton does not result in a unique definition for a line originating from a corner with an angle of pi, but surely drawing it perpendicular to the edges is the only sensible option?
What is causing this? Is this a bug in scikit-geometric/the underlying CGAL code? How can I fix it/find a workaround?
For this case (square with one extra point on the bottom) it does work the way I expect:
points = [[0, 0], [0.6, 0], 
          [1, 0], [1, 1], [ 0, 1]]


If I'm using CGAL 6.0 with your input the bisectors look correct.

Thanks, I'm not sure what version of CGAL scikit-geometry is using under the hood, but it looks like it's not CGAL 6.0. I'll see if I can upgrade either scikit-geometry or CGAL.
